# IISの接続数制限について

Tags: iis

IISの接続数制限について､何か正式なドキュメントまたはそれを定義している情報をご存じであればご教授ください｡

インターネットで探してはいるのですが､色々な記事があり､どれが本当なのか疑わしい状態です｡｡

ちなみに知りたいのはWindows 7, 8.1, 10のクライアントOSのIISについてです｡

よろしくお願いします｡

Comment: ここ [Limits for a Web Site <limits> : The Official Microsoft IIS Site](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits)  に `MaxConnections` という項目があり、デフォルト値が `4294967295` となっています。これは `2^32-1` と同値なので、接続数を 32bit 幅の `unsigned int` 型変数で管理しているということなのでしょうね。しかしこれは理論的な許容値であって、実際に 43 億弱のクライアントからの同時接続を捌けるということではないとは思います。

Comment: 早速のご返信､本当にありがとうございます｡　IISのバージョンによって接続数が変わる訳でもなさそうですね｡　ざっくりでいいのでご教授いただきたいのですが､クライアントOSのIISとサーバーOSのIISの違いは何かありますか?　質問ばかりで恐縮です｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS の違いについては情報を持っていませんが、サーバ OS とクライアント OS の違いなら。

Windows XP の場合 `C:\Windows\system32\eula.txt`
Windows 7, 10 の場合 `C:\Windows\system32\licence.rtf`
(Windows 8, 8.1 は手元にありません)
によるとクライアント OS をサーバ的利用する場合は接続数に上限があるとのことです。
XP の場合 10 接続 7, 10 の場合 20 接続が上限です。
管理者権限で `net config server` コマンドを起動してもそのことが確認できます。

IIS 側に制約が無くても OS (のライセンス同意書) による制約があるというわけです。
TCP/UDP レベルでの socket １つを「接続」と呼ぶらしいので、制約としては結構きついですね。

サーバ OS のほうはライセンスによる制約は無かったはずです。
（もちろん資源による制約はあります）

Comment: サーバOSにもライセンスの制約があります。原則としてユーザーもしくはデバイス数分のCAL、もしくは外部公開サーバであればそれ用のライセンスが必要です。例外的に追加ライセンスが不要名場合がありますが、MSのライセンスは解釈がややこしいので個別に確認したほうがよいです。

Comment: 貴重なお時間とご回答ありがとうございます｡　大変勉強になりました｡MSのライセンスは理解の"仕方"によるところがあるのでわかりづらいです｡｡　ライセンス､OSの接続数､IISの接続数を考慮しようと思います｡